# Failed download of images

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How would i know if i downloading of images failed?

What happens is that i download the image url first, and from there get the image filename to store to my database. Then have two methods to download from the url, and save is as the filename. Btw, they are being called by a method that is being called by an AsyncTask.

Here are the two methods (that are handed down by my senior) that is handles the download of the image files:

```
private void imageProcessing(String url, String filename) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    // String root1= getResources().getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage)
    File myDir = new File(root + "/arson/images");
    File nomedia = new File(myDir, ".nomedia");
    if (!nomedia.exists()) {
        Log.wtf("nomedia not exists", nomedia.getAbsolutePath().toString());
        try {
            nomedia.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.e("NEW FILE CREATION", e1.toString());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.wtf("nomedia exists", nomedia.getAbsolutePath().toString());
    }
    File file = new File(myDir, filename);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = downloadBitmap(url);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("BITMAP PROCESS", e.toString());
    }
}

public static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            return null;
        }
        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or
        // IllegalStateException
        getRequest.abort();
    } finally {
        if (client != null)
            client.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are using try catch block then you will get to know when something went wrong with your download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kind of possible issues here.

1) HTTP Status Code is not 200 : You are returning null if this happens, and when you get null you can know there has been a problem downloading.

2) HTTP Status Code is 200 but file download fails : You will either have an exception here, or none at all. If you have an exception you are already catching it. For the other case where there is no exception you have to change your implementation a little. You will have to save the downloaded file first (temp file), read the contentLength and verify that it matches with what you got from the server. If the contentLength is correct, you can then use BitmapFactory to read the file from the device.

Comment: Could it be SocketException? I can't find a reliable source to this. Maybe you've encountered this before?

Comment: I haven't directly encountered something like this before. But I use md5sum (server sends one for the file) and content length to verify that the file I downloaded is the right one. There are no exceptions for this, the only way we can know is by verifying it later.